# Split apart page break and paragraph mark with vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to do a search and replace on a document that finds all 'small' page breaks ('^m' in Word/VBA), and replaces them with a 'full' page break. These small page breaks all have a paragraph mark after them. When that is removed, they become a full page break.

How do I search and replace for all instances of "^m" and remove one character immediately to the right of any selection found?

In old versions of word, you could tick a box for 'split apart page break and paragraph marks', but no longer. The documents I'm working with are being fed through software that doesn't know how to read small page breaks, hence the need to remove the paragraph marker immediately after any that are found.

I've noticed this can be accomplished by replacing the '^m' with '^m ', which removes the paragraph marker after the page break and inserts a space instead, but then I can't seem to figure out how to remove the space immediately afterward (AND maintain the full sized page break).

```
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^m"
    .Replacement.Text = "^m "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.MoveRight
Selection.TypeBackspace
Selection.TypeBackspace
SendKeys ("{BACKSPACE}")
```

This code does, somehow, find 'small' page breaks, replace them with 'full' page breaks, and remove a space afterwards. However, when there's multiple page breaks in the document it introduces various issues, including random character deletion (not surprising considering the code).

Any help would be appreciated! I've managed to use VBA to do a lot of amazing things so far, but this (admittedly very basic) task has me stumped, as I don't fully understand how to use the selection/replacement code.

Comment: Update: I think I may have figured it out. Searching for ^m^p and replacing with ^m may do exactly what I'm looking for. Will update shortly if resolved.

Comment: So far so good using the replace with "^m" method on ^m^p. If anyone has a smarter way to go about it, feel free to contribute.

Comment: I don't think there'd be any better way...